# EF Core: Updating One-to-Many Relationship dependent entity id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am new in ASP.NET core and EF core. Please check my code and let me know what I am doing wrong.

** Foreign key constraint violation for AuthorId.
** BookCategory entity can not be tracked because another instance with same ID is being tracked

> Book Model

```
public class Book
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public int? Discount { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public int? Stock { get; set; }

        public Author Author { get; set; }
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }

        public BookCategory Category { get; set; }
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

        public ICollection<JoinBookTag> BookTags { get; set; }
    }
```

> BookCategory Model

```
public class BookCategory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }

    }
```

> Author Model

```
public class Author
    {
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
```

> BookController

```
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        private readonly HostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;


        [BindProperty]
        public BookViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
        public BookController(ApplicationDbContext db, HostingEnvironment host)
        {
            _db = db;
            _hostingEnvironment = host;
            ViewModel = new BookViewModel()
            {
                Book = new Models.Book(),
                Authors = _db.Authors.ToList(),
                BookCategories = _db.BookCategories.ToList(),
                Tags = _db.Tags.ToList()
            };
        }
```

> ...............

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var book = _db.Books.Include(b => b.Category)
                        .Include(b => b.Author)
                        .SingleOrDefault(b => b.BookId == id);
            if (book == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            ViewModel.Book = book;
            return View(ViewModel);
        }

[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(BookViewModel model, int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (id != model.Book.BookId)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                /*ViewModel.Book = model.Book;
                return View(ViewModel);*/
                var errors = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors)
                           .Where(y => y.Count > 0)
                           .ToList();
                return Json(new { errors });
            }
            var dbModel = _db.Books.Include(b => b.Category).Where(b => b.BookId == id).FirstOrDefault();

            var file = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
            if (file.Count > 0)
            {
                var RootDirectory = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
                var extension = Path.GetExtension(file[0].FileName);
                var filePath = Path.Combine(DataContext.ImageDirectory, model.Book.BookId + extension);
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(RootDirectory, filePath), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file[0].CopyTo(fileStream);
                }

                dbModel.ImagePath = @"/" + filePath;
            }
            dbModel.AuthorId = model.Book.AuthorId;
            dbModel.CategoryId = model.Book.CategoryId;
            dbModel.Discount = model.Book.Discount;
            dbModel.Price = model.Book.Price;
            dbModel.Stock = model.Book.Stock;
            dbModel.Title = model.Book.Title;

            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the key attribute on your id properties inside your models.

The next thing you need to update is tell _db to update your entity first then and only then save changes.

Why are you using async and await? Are these controller actions slowing down the UI?

Also can you post your book view model?

You action methods are wrong in certain places. Let me know if you want some more detailed advice.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
    { 
       //Give this a name other than view model for example BookViewModel
       ViewModel model = new ViewModel();

        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var book = _db.Books.Include(b => b.Category)
                    .Include(b => b.Author)
                    .SingleOrDefault(b => b.BookId == id);

        if (book == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        model.Book = book;

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(BookViewModel model, int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || id != model.Book.BookId)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var dbModel = _db.Books.Include(b => b.Category).Where(b => b.BookId == id).FirstOrDefault();

        var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
        if (files.Any())
        {
            var RootDirectory = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(files[0].FileName);
            var filePath = Path.Combine(DataContext.ImageDirectory, model.Book.BookId + extension);
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(RootDirectory, filePath), FileMode.Create))
            {
                file[0].CopyTo(fileStream);
            }

            dbModel.ImagePath = @"/" + filePath;
        }

        dbModel.AuthorId = model.Book.AuthorId;
        dbModel.CategoryId = model.Book.CategoryId;
        dbModel.Discount = model.Book.Discount;
        dbModel.Price = model.Book.Price;
        dbModel.Stock = model.Book.Stock;
        dbModel.Title = model.Book.Title;

        await _db.Books.UpdateAsync(dbModel);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

        }

        return View(model);

    }
```

Comment: Yes, of course
Please provide some more detailed answer

Comment: Try that. But be careful with async await. Why are you using Async/Await?

Comment: I am a newbie, you know. Anyway, I read that it is a good practice to use them during database operations.

Comment: it really depends on the context. usually its only when you the ui is being blocked. you stick the work onto another thread letting the ui thread continue. If you are a newbie stick with basics. Only use something if there is a real need for it.

Comment: @Mdkhalidhasan It is recommended to use async/await. Does your issue exist after adding `await _db.Books.UpdateAsync(dbModel);`?